# Finding count of records in given interval

Tags: sql-server, dateinterval

I have a table with user logins, and I want to find the user who logged in to the site more than 3 times in a 5 day period.

For example my table is:

```
id | user_id | login_date 
---+---------+--------------
 1 |    10   | 10.1.2014 00:00
 2 |    10   | 11.1.2014 10:10
 3 |    12   | 11.1.2014 11:00
 4 |    10   | 11.1.2014 12:00
 5 |    12   | 12.1.2014 00:00
 6 |    10   | 13.1.2014 10:00
 7 |    12   | 18.1.2014 00:00
 8 |    12   | 22.1.2014 09:00
```

For this example table, I want to choose user_id 10 because he/she logged in more than 3 times in a 5 day period.

Could you please help me for that?

edit: i forgot to mention that database is sql server 2008

Comment: do you want this for rolling periods of 5 days or for a give period like the last 5 days?

Comment: Tanner: i want to search for rolling periods, not last 5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by self joining the table on `user_id` where the `JOIN` takes records that are within 5 days of the record it is joining to like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #login
    (
      id INT ,
      user_id INT ,
      login_date DATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO #login
        ( id, user_id, login_date )
VALUES  ( 1, 10, '2014-01-10 00:00' ),
        ( 2, 10, '2014-01-11 10:10' ),
        ( 3, 12, '2014-01-11 11:00' ),
        ( 4, 10, '2014-01-11 12:00' ),
        ( 5, 12, '2014-01-12 00:00' ),
        ( 6, 10, '2014-01-13 10:00' ),
        ( 7, 12, '2014-01-18 00:00' ),
        ( 8, 12, '2014-01-22 09:00' )

SELECT  t1.user_id ,
        t1.login_date AS FirstDateInLoginPeriod ,
        COUNT(t2.user_id) AS LoginCount
FROM    #login t1
        INNER JOIN #login t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                  AND t2.login_date 
                      BETWEEN t1.login_date AND DATEADD(DAY, 5, t1.login_date)
GROUP BY t1.user_id ,
        t1.login_date
HAVING  COUNT(t2.user_id) > 3

DROP TABLE #login
```

Produces:

```
user_id  FirstDateInLoginPeriod     LoginCount
----------------------------------------------
10       2014-01-10 00:00:00.000    4
```

Comment: Hi Tanner, thanks for the solution. It works. But i created a new table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45352/1

Now login counts increasing to 40. Why is that?

Comment: @doganhisa the reason you see 40 is because the sample data you added all have the same login datetime, so the JOIN is retunring more records than you want, which in reality you wouldn't see. You would expect the login time to be different on each row. If you modify the time portion of the values, you'll see it counts them correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57aaa/1

Comment: thank you for explanation. For example if we suppose we have erroneous records on table (it is not impossible that login dates are the same but lets suppose it is) how can we show the correct login count ? Is there a way for that. I mean how can we fix that login count will not show 40, that can show 8.

Comment: @doganhisa Assuming login_date is a date time, you shouldn't have repeated values (down to the millisecond), so this solution will work. This error was produced on dummy data. I would run some queries on your large dataset, `group by user_id, login_date having count > 1` to see if the login_date has ever been repeated for a user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ then you can use `LEAD` window function to calculate difference in days between any 3 consecutive records:

```
select distinct USER_ID
from (
select USER_ID, 
       datediff(d, login_date,
                   LEAD(login_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                                             ORDER BY login_date)) as diffDates
from users ) t
where t.diffDates <= 5
```

Then simply select those `USER_IDs` for which the difference in days is equal to or less than 5.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d839/6)

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or 2005, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` in conjuction with a self join in order to simulate `LEAD` function:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT id, user_id, login_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_date) AS rn
   FROM users
) 
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM (             
   SELECT c1.user_id, 
          DATEDIFF(d, c1.login_date, c2.login_date) AS diffInDays
   FROM CTE AS c1
   INNER JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.user_id = c2.user_id AND c1.rn = c2.rn - 2
  ) t
WHERE t.diffInDays <= 5
```

`diffInDays` in the above query is essentially the rolling difference in days between any 3 consecutive user logins.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d839/13)

Comment: @doganhisa the cte approach here does work to identify 3 logins within  a day 5 period. A side note on this is that if you want to output the number of logins, it won't produce the correct count as you can see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/421ad/2, the result should show 8 but it shows 6. This is outside of the scope of the question, but thought I'd add it in case you planned to add that information in future.

Comment: thanks for the information, in fact i didnt need login count when asking, but  after you mention it can be useful to have login count too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to get your result.

As you can see you can use `DATEADD` function for calculating reference date and use having to filter logins count to be more or equal 3

```
Select count(*),user_id 
from table_name 
where login_date>=DATEADD (day,-5,GETDATE())
group by user_id  
having COUNT(*) >=3
```